# What difficulties should I expect if I write a NoSQL db using golang but want to run Hadoop mapreduce on it?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, go

I would like to build a distributed NoSQL database or key-value store using golang, to learn golang and practice distribute system knowledge I've learnt from school. The target use case I can think of is running MapReduce on top of it, and implement a HDFS-compatible "filesystem" to expose the data to Hadoop, similar to running Hadoop on Ceph and Amazon S3.

My question is, what difficulties should I expect to integrate such an NoSQl database with Hadoop? Or integrate with other languages (e.g., providing Ruby/Python/Node.js/C++ APIs?) if I use golang to build the system.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're planning to do? This is an interesting question but a bit broad. I wrote a (non distributed) NoSQL database in Go so I can share some insight.

Comment: Basically, my current plan is building a distributed NoSQL, might be a Key-value store, that is designed for high reliability, also designed for high write performance. It should be able to be the backend storage for hadoop MapReduce tasks, so we can run "hadoop jar foo.jar gonosql://some/key/prefix" to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm not much of a Hadoop user so I'll give you some more general lessons learned about the issues you'll face:

1. Protocol. If you're going with REST Go will be fine, but expect to find some gotchas in the default HTTP library's defaults (not expiring idle keepalive connections, not necessarily knowing when a reader has closed a stream). But if you want something more compact, know that: a. the Thrift implementation for Go, last I checked, was lacking and relatively slow. b. Go has great support for RPC but it might not play well with other languages. So you might want to check out protobuf, or work on top the redis protocol or something like that.
2. GC. Go's GC is very simplistic (STW, not generational, etc). If you plan on heavy memory caching in the orders of multiple Gs, expect GC pauses all over the place. There are techniques to reduce GC pressure but the straight forward Go idioms aren't usually optimized for that.
3. mmap'ing in Go is not straightforward, so it will be a bit of a struggle if you want to leverage that.
4. Besides slices, lists and maps, you won't have a lot of built in data structures to work with, like a Set type. There are tons of good implementations of them out there, but you'll have to do some digging up.
5. Take the time to learn concurrency patterns and interface patterns in Go. It's a bit different than other languages, and as a rule of thumb, if you find yourself struggling with a pattern from other languages, you're probably doing it wrong. A good talk about Go concurrency is this one IMHO http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDDwwePbDtw

A few projects you might want to have a look at:

1. Groupcache - a distributed key/value cache written in Go by Brad Fitzpatrick for Google's own use. It's a great implementation of a simple yet super robust distributed system in Go. https://github.com/golang/groupcache and check out Brad's presentation about it: http://talks.golang.org/2013/oscon-dl.slide
2. InfluxDB which includes a Go based version of the great Raft algorithm: https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb
3. My own humble (pretty dead) project, a redis compliant database that's based on a plugin architecture. My Go has improved since, but it has some nice parts, and it includes a pretty fast server for the redis protocol. https://bitbucket.org/dvirsky/boilerdb